# Best practice for readOnly / edition modes in JSF?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, composite-component

Anyone can suggest a way to perform the edition/read-only modes? I am using PF, and I have done this:

```
<composite:interface>
        <composite:attribute name="size"/>
        <composite:attribute name="value"/>
        <composite:attribute name="editable"/>
    </composite:interface>

    <composite:implementation>

        <p:inputText value="#{cc.attrs.value}"  size="#{cc.attrs.size}" rendered="#{cc.attrs.editable}"/>

        <h:outputText value="#{cc.attrs.value}" rendered="#{!cc.attrs.editable}"/>

    </composite:implementation>
```

Just displaying an inputText or outPutText depending on a boolean. But apparently there's a bug in PF's inputText, as I receive a targetClass null exception. If I use inputText outside the componente it works, but I want to encapsulate this behaviour withing a comp. Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest to use the `disabled` attribute instead and if necessary use CSS to style the input to look like an output.

E.g.

```xml
<p:inputText value="#{bean.value}" disabled="#{!bean.editable}" />
```

with CSS

```css
.ui-inputfield[disabled], .ui-inputfield[disabled].ui-state-focus {
    border: 0 !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    outline: 0 !important;
}
```